# Reading file in "rb" mode while the file is changing

Tags: python, file, bytesio

Imagine that you are reading the byte contents of a file in python, with the goal of writing them to a temporary file or bytesio.

What I have not been able to answer is what will happen if say the file is large and while it's open there's a change in the file?

Is there a way to ensure that the file is read correctly, without errors?

I would have dealt with that by simply copying it in the memory first but this doesn't seem to be wise in the scenario of large files.

Comment: How is it changing? Arbitrary bytes anywhere in the file, or just new data being appended to the end?

Comment: The standard solution would be to lock the file so that only the reader or the writer can access it at once. However, that would only ensure that the file doesn't change while the reader has the lock, not that it hasn't changed in some way since the last time the reader had the lock.

Comment: (It also requires the writer to cooperate by respecting the lock.)

Comment: Yeah it's not only new data being appended to the end, it could be wherever.